# Set Cron Job for 1st working day of every month in Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm new to scripting language, can anyone please explain how to set the cron job for 1st working day?

Comment: See http://www.switchplane.com/blog/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-weekday-of-the-month/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, run the date command:

```
$ date '+%x'
> 12/29/2014
```

%x tells date to display today's date in the format of the current locale. Using that exact same format, put a list of holidays in a file called holidays. For example:

```
$ cat holidays
> 01/01/2015
> 07/04/2015
```

Next, create the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
dom=$(date '+%d') # 01-31, day of month
year=$(date '+%Y') # four-digit year
month=$(date '+%m') # two-digit month

nworkdays=0
for d in $(seq 1 $dom)
do
    today=$(date -d "$year-$month-$d" '+%x') # locale's date representation (e.g. 12/31/99)
    dow=$(date -d "$year-$month-$d" '+%u')   # day of week: 1-7 with 1=Monday, 7=Sunday
    if [ "$dow" -le 5 ]  && grep -vq "$today" /path/holidays
    then
        workday=Yes
        nworkdays=$((nworkdays+1))
    else
        workday=
    fi
done
[ "$workday" ] && [ "$nworkdays" -eq 1 ] && /path/command
```

Comment: I have a query @Kir Chou.
 If suppose dom=31 today=12/31/2014 if [ "$dow" -le 5 ] && grep -vq "$today" /path/holidays ( this condition will be true since 31st Dec is not an holiday) It will enter into the loop. workday=Yes nworkdays=1 here [ "$workday" ] && [ "$nworkdays" -eq 1 ] && /path/command (the condition is true) But my doubt is how come this will its the 1st working day or not? the condition will be true for all the working days... After the 1st working day the script should not run...

Comment: Maybe you can try to use `break` if you assert that day is holiday.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following,

```
@monthly
```

Run once a month at the morning of the first day of the month.

```
0 0 1 * * /home/scripts/your_script_file.sh
```

**3rd Edit:**

This will run your job at morning say 10 AM on the first weekday of the month:

```
# First weekday of the month

# Monday - Friday
00 10 1-3 * * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Mon" ] && /home/scripts/your_script_file.sh
00 10 1 * * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Tue" ] && /home/scripts/your_script_file.sh
00 10 1 * * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Wed" ] && /home/scripts/your_script_file.sh
00 10 1 * * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Thu" ] && /home/scripts/your_script_file.sh
00 10 1 * * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Fri" ] && /home/scripts/your_script_file.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need how to set the corn job for 1st working day of every month and not 1st day of every month.

Comment: Just to check - you actually mean '1st weekday' of the month and not '1st working day' of the month (wrt some holiday-calendar),  for example the former will happily run Mon Jan 1 which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: If suppose i have to set cronjob for 5th working day?? How do i set it? @Skynet

Comment: Anymore answer for this??? I need to set cron job 1st working day of the month......

Comment: This is a confusing answer, only the content below "3rd Edit" actually answers the question. Why was this answer not cleaned up after the edits?

Answer (score 1):

Solution I have figured out:

```
0 9 1-3 * * [[ $(date +\%u) -lt 6 && (( $(date +\%d) -eq 1 || $(date +\%u) -eq 1 )) ]] && /home/scripts/your_script_file.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, I took the time to understand this instead of blindly copypasting, and I appreciate your clever logic around preventing multiple runs by first ensuring it's a weekday then checking if it's either day 1 of the month, or Monday (in which case the previous 1 or 2 days were not weekdays)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
59 6 1W * ?
```

Starts at AM6:59 every month at first Weekday.

Comment: What if the first working day in a month is not a Monday?

Comment: @Cpt_Jauchefuerst, you are right, `0 59 6 ? * MON#1` wouldn't work. Updated the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that that it still is not correct. Cron syntax is: MINUTE HOUR DOM MONTH DOW

Comment: Cron can have seconds also, wikipedia: _In some uses of the CRON format there is also a seconds field at the beginning of the pattern. In that case, the CRON expression is a string comprising 6 or 7 fields._
But for clarity I edited the answer to without seconds setting.

Answer (score -1):

a simple one 
 run the scripte at 08:00 every first of the month for workdays **Mon** to **Fri**

```
00 8 1 * 1-5 /path/to/your_script_file.sh
```

Comment: This is incorrect as it will run it every Mon-Fri _and_ on the 1st of the month. See https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?crontab(5) 
"Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields --
     day of month, and day of week.  If both fields are restricted (ie, are
     not *), the command will be run when either field matches the current
     time.  For example, ``30 4 1,15 * 5'' would cause a command to be run at
     4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday."