# Cron Trigger on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to get a job to run the first wednesday of the month AFTER the first sunday. From what I gathered the code is:

> H 12 4-10/1 * 3

But I get that the code is ran on all wednesdays.

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Cron Job for 1st working day of every month in Shell Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799958/set-cron-job-for-1st-working-day-of-every-month-in-shell-scripting)

Comment: It's not an *exact* duplicate, but you can add a check to see that the day of the month is greater than or equal to 4.

Comment: what do you mean by _a check_ ? 
and will Jenkins Scheduler understand the [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Thu" ]  portion of it?
@BenjaminW.

Comment: Oh, hmm... the `[ ... ]` test is part of the command, interpreted by the shell. I'm not sure about Jenkins, does it only accept the five date and time fields?

Comment: I'll remove the duplicate vote.